# Correct solution to IMO problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

This problem comes from the 1975 IMO Q4. It is stated as follows:

Let $f(n)$ be the digit sum of the integer $n$. ($f(57)=12, f(63)=9$,...). Let $N$=$4444^{4444}$. Find $f(f(n))$.

Proof: Well, consider this (mod $9$). i.e., first lets find a pattern: $4444$=$7$(mod $9$), $4444^2$=$7^2$=$4$(mod $9$), $4444^3$=$7^27$=$1$(mod $9$). Then notice that $4444$=$3(1481)$+$1$, which would then imply $f(4444^{4444})$=$f(f(4444^{4444}))$=$4444^{4444}$(mod $9$), which is $7$. So $f(f(N))$=$7$.

Is my solution correct? Namely that of $7$?

Comment: No, it is not correct.  The answer is $16$.   I don't understand your method at all.  Yes, we know that $f(n)\equiv 7 \pmod 9$.  So what?

Comment: The question is to find $f(f(f(n)))$ btw.

Comment: @jMdA  Oh, well in that case the answer is indeed $7$.  Though that's not the question presented here nor does it follow from anything in the post that I can see.

Comment: @lulu How did you solve this so quickly? Took me a few minutes to get my head around how to approach this.

Comment: @DonThousand  Yeah, should have said:  nothing intelligent.  [Brute force](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=digit+sum+4444%5E4444).  I was just trying to check/refute the result.

Comment: @lulu Yea, I only figured it out as fast as I did once I observed that the answer was $7$ from your comment, which immediately made me think to establish an upper bound on $f(f(f(n)))$.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNPq4VKD7ic&t=662s&ab_channel=blackpenredpen

Comment: So if we have that we want to solve $f(f(f(n)))$, did I get it right?

Comment: @toolfan3 But you didn't solve $f(f(f(n)))$... $f(f(n))=16$, as lulu found.